# Recurse over childNodes

Tags: javascript, nodelist, child-nodes

Take a look at the code below, with the console open. There are a handful of nodes logged to the console.

```js
function recurseChildren(element) {
  var children = element.childNodes,
    length = children.length;

  if (length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      console.dir(children[i]);
      recurseChildren(children[i]);
    }
  }
}

recurseChildren(document.body);
```

Then run this in the console: `document.body.childNodes.length;`

There's 23 logged at that point.

Shouldn't the `recurseChildren()` function do a `console.dir` of a whole lot of items?

Comment: The script is run inside of a smaller sandbox in an iframe, not the main Stack Overflow page. Paste your code snippet into your console and you'll see what you would expect.

Comment: Perfect. The issue was noticed on a snippet running on CodePen. So it was the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different environments.  You're running the script from stackoverflow's editor and then running `document.body.childNodes.length` in your console for the site.  stackoverflow's editor is constrained to an iframe with minimal code.  If you open your console and view the output after running this script, you'll notice that it isn't 23 but 2 or thereabouts (running `document.body.childNodes.length` in my console for SO gave me 25).

```js
console.log(document.body.childNodes.length);
document.write('total nodes in this iframe: ' + document.body.childNodes.length);
```

Comment: Yep. Iframes have their own document context. Thanks for the answer.